# AttributeError: 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_autoscaleXon'

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, cartopy

I am trying to run a code that uses cartopy and I am getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_autoscaleXon'

I downgraded matplotlib to previous version (3.5) and upgrade cartopy but I am still getting the same error.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: See:  https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/2086

Comment: saw it and I tried every solution from there, I created a new environment and worked for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

> Update: See my comments below, but this won't work for all environment configurations. If I find a more robust solution, I'll update. This solution could work for some people though, so I'll leave it for now.

A bit late on this, but I was also having this issue and not really having any luck on re-installing Cartopy or changing my environment. A quick work-around though is to add the property to your plot axes yourself. It worked for me at least. I did the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

transform = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=transform)

ax._autoscaleXon = False
ax._autoscaleYon = False

# Continue to make your plot below without error.
```

This obviously is not ideal, but it did work for me and now I can stop messing around with my environment.

Comment: I've found an instance where this did not work. So it will only work for some configurations. If I figure something out I'll update my post.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It's producing the same error Attribute error.

Comment: Yeah, @Pixel_Bear, I have a new environment configuration that does this too, so the work around was short lived. It seems now that the reference to those attributes is in the `add_subplot` call. When I have some time, I might see if there is a way to make a subclass that explicitly sets those attributes so that it happens within that call. If I manage it, I'll update my answer here.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I made a new environment and installed cartopy lib first. It worked fine. My old environment had been bloated, so maybe that's why it suddenly threw this error one day. Coincidence, I'm also a physicist who worked with satellite data. I can't resist asking, what tools you use to calibrate earth obs. sats?@tmwilson26

Comment: @Pixel_Bear That makes sense. I had the problem after building new virtual environments all at once instead of starting from something with cartopy installed first when the error happened again. Thats cool that you are also working with satellite data :) We build a lot of our tools in house as the calculations themselves aren't too complex, but I get a lot of mileage out of SpiceyPy to do orbital and pointing analysis. Can't recommend that enough for working with satellite data.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem starting with `cartopy` 0.18 and `matplotlib` 3.5.2 and `matplotlib-base` 3.6.3 and got the error about autoscaling.

I uninstalled `cartopy` and then tried to install `cartopy` 0.21 as follows:

```
conda install cartopy
pip install cartopy==0.21
pip install cartopy
```

I keep getting build errors telling me I need to upgrade Microsoft C++ to version 14 or higher
(which I had).

Finally I went to
[https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html]

I first followed their instructions about dependencies:

1. pip install GEO (installed GEOS-0.2.3)
2. pip install shapely (requirement already satisfied)
3. pip install pyshp (already satisfied)

then I ran this install:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cartopy
```

(installed cartopy-0.21.1 and shapely-2.0.1)

now it works. Note, not sure when I was doing conda install before why it would not build and this time it did. I don't think conda-forge was my default channel.

[image: 200 mb winds]